# Lost Android's OS

Tags: battery, charging, motorola-moto-g

I bought a Moto G (1st gen). It was upgrading and had around 1% battery and was charging, but simultaneously I unplugged the charger and the mobile turned off and now it's not turning on. It's not getting even in download mode. I tried starting it in download mode, but nothing is happening. The company I bought the mobile from installs Android too, so there must be some way out.

Answer (score 1):

First charge your device for an hour. Maybe it is not turning on for lack of charge. Then follow this steps:

1. Download the **firmware** as per your device model from [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/index-moto-g-falcon-factory-firmware-t3110795)
2. Download and install **Moto G drivers** on your PC from [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2550635)
3. Install **Minimal ADB & Fastboot** in your PC from [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=42407269)
4. Now when your device is in switch off mode, then Press and hold 'Volume down' then power on the phone. your phone should reboot into bootloader mode. when it successfully booted into bootloader, follow the step "**2)**" and then step "**3b)**" form [This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2542219) post.

Your phone's firmware will be restored successfully!

Comment: But my phone is doing nothing....not even starting...wat should I do?

Comment: Where should I ansta

Comment: Where should I install firmware...?

Comment: When I connect phone to my laptop it shows nothing....

Comment: And how can I start my phone when it is not even starting...

Comment: My phone is charged

Comment: When I plug in the charger,  the led notification glows and then turns off

Comment: Press and hold **Volume down** and **Power** Button together for 5secs and then release both. Tell me if your device reboots into bootloader mode after pressing this combination.

Comment: No... i am sorry but it is not getting into bootloader mode...i have tried everything that I could....but yes when the the phone is in charging, after pressing  the power and volume down button,  the led notification glows and then fturns off suddenly.....please help me....how can I overcome this problem....i just want my phone back....their must be be some other way....? Isn't. It so?...please help me....much appriciated..